# Executor shows up on the spark UI even on killing the worker and stages keep on failing with java.io.IOException

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

I am running a spark streaming application with spark version 1.4.0

If I kill the worker (using kill -9) when my job is running, then the worker and executor both on that node dies,but it still shows up in the executors tab of the UI. The number of active tasks sometimes shows as negative on those executors.

Because of this the jobs keep on failing with the following exception

```
16/04/01 23:54:20 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 141.0 in stage 19859.0 (TID 190333, 192.168.33.96): java.io.IOException: Failed to connect to /192.168.33.97:63276
        at org.apache.spark.network.client.TransportClientFactory.createClient(TransportClientFactory.java:193)
        at org.apache.spark.network.client.TransportClientFactory.createClient(TransportClientFactory.java:156)
        at org.apache.spark.network.netty.NettyBlockTransferService$$anon$1.createAndStart(NettyBlockTransferService.scala:88)
        at org.apache.spark.network.shuffle.RetryingBlockFetcher.fetchAllOutstanding(RetryingBlockFetcher.java:140)
        at org.apache.spark.network.shuffle.RetryingBlockFetcher.access$200(RetryingBlockFetcher.java:43)
        at org.apache.spark.network.shuffle.RetryingBlockFetcher$1.run(RetryingBlockFetcher.java:170)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: /192.168.33.97:63276
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:716)
        at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel.doFinishConnect(NioSocketChannel.java:208)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioChannel$AbstractNioUnsafe.finishConnect(AbstractNioChannel.java:287)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:528)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:468)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:382)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:354)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:116)
        ... 1 more
```

On relaunching the worker a new executor is allocated but the old (dead) executor's entry is still there and the stages fail with "java.io.IOException: Failed to connect to " error.